# tensorflow multiply two layers

Tags: tensorflow, input, tensor

I do have two inputs to my network. The one input gets feed through a few linear layers and then should be multiplied elementwise with the other input.

```
    input_a = Input(shape=input_a_shape)
    x = Dense(side_channel_speed_output_dimension, activation="relu")(x)
    x = tf.reshape(x, [input_shape_image[0], input_shape_image[1]])

    x = tf.expand_dims(x, input_shape_image[2])
    x = tf.repeat(x, repeats=input_shape_image[2], axis=2)

    input_b = Input(shape=input_shape_b)
```

At this stage I would like to multiply input_a and input_b. How do I do that?

I tried:

```
input = keras.layers.multiply([input_b, input_a])
```

There I got this error:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_2:0", shape=(None, 60, 40, 2), dtype=float32) at layer "input_2". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: ['input_1', 'dense', 'tf_op_layer_Reshape', 'tf_op_layer_ExpandDims', 'tf_op_layer_Repeat/Shape', 'tf_op_layer_Repeat/strided_slice', 'tf_op_layer_Repeat/strided_slice_1', 'tf_op_layer_Repeat/ExpandDims', 'tf_op_layer_Repeat/Tile', 'tf_op_layer_Repeat/concat']
```

I also tried just `tf.multipy(a,b)`. It does not work either.

Does someone know, how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: input_a = Input(shape=input_a_shape)
x = Dense(side_channel_speed_output_dimension, activation="relu")(x)<-this x should be input_a right?

Answer (score 0):

I got it now. I need to use this function:

```
x = keras.layers.multiply([input_image, x])
```